# ipmptool get the Board Serial using raw command

Tags: ipmitool

I would like to use `ipmitool` to get the Board Serial Number, currently I can use `$ sudo ipmitool fru` to query the information as below:

```
$ sudo ipmitool fru
FRU Device Description : Builtin FRU Device (ID 0)
 Chassis Type          : Main Server Chassis
 Chassis Part Number   : 01234567
 Chassis Serial        : 01234567890123456789AB
 Board Mfg Date        : Wed Jan  7 13:07:00 2015
 Board Mfg             : GIGABYTE
 Board Product         : MB10-DS4
 Board Serial          : GG3P8800012
 Board Part Number     : 01234567
 Product Manufacturer  : GIGABYTE
 Product Name          : MB10-DS4
 Product Part Number   : 000000000001
 Product Version       : 0100
 Product Serial        : 01234567890123456789AB
 Product Asset Tag     : 01234567890123456789AB
```

Because in my project, I need to use OpenIPMI API in C code to get the Board Serial, I think that should be unique.
So, I use the raw command:

```
$ sudo ipmitool raw
Not enough parameters given.
RAW Commands:  raw <netfn> <cmd> [data]

Network Function Codes:

  VAL   HEX     STRING
==============================================
  0     0x00    Chassis
  2     0x02    Bridge
  4     0x04    SensorEvent
  6     0x06    Application
  8     0x08    Firmware
  10    0x0a    Storage
  12    0x0c    Transport

(can also use raw hex values)
```

Then, try to issue following command for to know more about the raw command format

```
$ sudo ipmitool raw 0 0
 01 20 20 20 20 20
$ sudo ipmitool raw 0 1
 21 00 00 70
$ sudo ipmitool raw 0 2
Unable to send RAW command (channel=0x0 netfn=0x0 lun=0x0 cmd=0x2 rsp=0xc7): 
Request data length invalid
```

I've googled for several days, but can not find any information, and I've downloaded the source code of ipmitool, maybe I'll try to read the source code more clearly.

BTW, I've downloaded the IPMI utility 'IPMICFG' from SuperMicro, 
and follow the guide [Supermicro IPMI Device Configuration](https://alnitech.com/news/supermicro-ipmi-device-configuration-using-ipmicfg/) using IPMICFG, and read [A Gentle Introduction with OpenIPMI](http://openipmi.sourceforge.net/IPMI.pdf).

My Question is, what is the `netfn` code should I use, and what is the command to get the Board Serial, is this case, the value should be `GG3P8800012`.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

---

Thanks @Lenniey

Here is the output of `sudo ipmitool fru -vvv`:

```
$ sudo ipmitool fru -vvv
Using ipmi device 0
Set IPMB address to 0x20
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0x6
  cmd       = 0x1
Iana: 15370
Running Get PICMG Properties my_addr 0x20, transit 0, target 0
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0x2c
  cmd       = 0x0
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (1 bytes)
 00
Error response 0xc1 from Get PICMG Properities
Running Get VSO Capabilities my_addr 0x20, transit 0, target 0
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0x2c
  cmd       = 0x0
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (1 bytes)
 03
Invalid completion code received: Invalid command
Acquire IPMB address
Discovered IPMB address 0x0
Interface address: my_addr 0x20 transit 0:0 target 0x20:0 ipmb_target 0

FRU Device Description : Builtin FRU Device (ID 0)
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0x6
  cmd       = 0x1
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x10
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (1 bytes)
 00
fru.size = 2048 bytes (accessed by bytes)
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x11
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (4 bytes)
 00 00 00 08
 FRU DATA (9 bytes)
 08 01 00 01 07 0e 00 00 e9
fru.header.version:         0x1
fru.header.offset.internal: 0x0
fru.header.offset.chassis:  0x8
fru.header.offset.board:    0x38
fru.header.offset.product:  0x70
fru.header.offset.multi:    0x0
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x11
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (4 bytes)
 00 08 00 02
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x11
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (4 bytes)
 00 08 00 21
Retrying FRU read with request size 25
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x11
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (4 bytes)
 00 08 00 19
Retrying FRU read with request size 24
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x11
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (4 bytes)
 00 08 00 18
Retrying FRU read with request size 23
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x11
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (4 bytes)
 00 08 00 17
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x11
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (4 bytes)
 00 1f 00 17
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x11
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (4 bytes)
 00 36 00 02
 Chassis Type          : Main Server Chassis
 Chassis Part Number   : 01234567
 Chassis Serial        : 01234567890123456789AB
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x11
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (4 bytes)
 00 38 00 02
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
   cmd       = 0x11
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (4 bytes)
 00 38 00 17
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x11
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (4 bytes)
 00 4f 00 17
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x11
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (4 bytes)
 00 66 00 0a
 Board Mfg Date        : Wed Jan  7 13:07:00 2015
 Board Mfg             : GIGABYTE
 Board Product         : MB10-DS4
 Board Serial          : GG3P8800012
 Board Part Number     : 01234567
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x11
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (4 bytes)
 00 70 00 02
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x11
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (4 bytes)
 00 70 00 17
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x11
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (4 bytes)
 00 87 00 17
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x11
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (4 bytes)
 00 9e 00 17
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x11
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (4 bytes)
 00 b5 00 17
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x11
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (4 bytes)
 00 cc 00 04
 Product Manufacturer  : GIGABYTE
 Product Name          : MB10-DS4
 Product Part Number   : 000000000001
 Product Version       : 0100
 Product Serial        : 01234567890123456789AB
 Product Asset Tag     : 01234567890123456789AB

OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0x6
  cmd       = 0x1
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x20
SDR free space: 14864
SDR records   : 25
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x22
SDR reservation ID 0002
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x23
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (6 bytes)
 02 00 00 00 00 05
SDR record ID   : 0x0000
SDR record id mismatch: 0x0001
SDR record type : 0x12
SDR record next : 0x0002
SDR record bytes: 16
Getting 16 bytes from SDR at offset 5
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x23
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (6 bytes)
 02 00 00 00 05 10
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x23
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (6 bytes)
 02 00 02 00 00 05
SDR record ID   : 0x0002
SDR record type : 0xc0
SDR record next : 0x0003
SDR record bytes: 11
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x23
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (6 bytes)
 02 00 03 00 00 05
SDR record ID   : 0x0003
SDR record type : 0x01
SDR record next : 0x0009
SDR record bytes: 52
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x23
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (6 bytes)
 02 00 09 00 00 05
SDR record ID   : 0x0009
SDR record type : 0x01
SDR record next : 0x000a
SDR record bytes: 53
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x23
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (6 bytes)
 02 00 0a 00 00 05
SDR record ID   : 0x000a
SDR record type : 0x01
SDR record next : 0x000c
SDR record bytes: 53
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x23
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (6 bytes)
 02 00 0c 00 00 05
SDR record ID   : 0x000c
SDR record type : 0x01
SDR record next : 0x000d
SDR record bytes: 53
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x23
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (6 bytes)
 02 00 0d 00 00 05
SDR record ID   : 0x000d
SDR record type : 0x01
SDR record next : 0x003b
SDR record bytes: 53
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x23
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (6 bytes)
 02 00 3b 00 00 05
SDR record ID   : 0x003b
SDR record type : 0x01
SDR record next : 0x003c
SDR record bytes: 47
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x23
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (6 bytes)
 02 00 3c 00 00 05
SDR record ID   : 0x003c
SDR record type : 0x01
SDR record next : 0x003d
SDR record bytes: 46
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x23
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (6 bytes)
 02 00 3d 00 00 05
SDR record ID   : 0x003d
SDR record type : 0x01
SDR record next : 0x003e
SDR record bytes: 47
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x23
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (6 bytes)
 02 00 3e 00 00 05
SDR record ID   : 0x003e
SDR record type : 0x01
SDR record next : 0x0040
SDR record bytes: 51
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x23
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (6 bytes)
 02 00 40 00 00 05
SDR record ID   : 0x0040
SDR record type : 0x01
SDR record next : 0x0041
SDR record bytes: 49
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x23
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (6 bytes)
 02 00 41 00 00 05
SDR record ID   : 0x0041
SDR record type : 0x01
SDR record next : 0x0043
SDR record bytes: 53
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x23
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (6 bytes)
 02 00 43 00 00 05
SDR record ID   : 0x0043
SDR record type : 0x01
SDR record next : 0x0047
SDR record bytes: 52
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x23
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (6 bytes)
 02 00 47 00 00 05
SDR record ID   : 0x0047
SDR record type : 0x01
SDR record next : 0x0048
SDR record bytes: 53
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x23
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (6 bytes)
 02 00 48 00 00 05
SDR record ID   : 0x0048
SDR record type : 0x01
SDR record next : 0x0049
SDR record bytes: 52
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x23
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (6 bytes)
 02 00 49 00 00 05
SDR record ID   : 0x0049
SDR record type : 0x01
SDR record next : 0x004a
SDR record bytes: 57
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x23
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (6 bytes)
 02 00 4a 00 00 05
SDR record ID   : 0x004a
SDR record type : 0x01
SDR record next : 0x0088
SDR record bytes: 56
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x23
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (6 bytes)
 02 00 88 00 00 05
SDR record ID   : 0x0088
SDR record type : 0x01
SDR record next : 0x008a
SDR record bytes: 51
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x23
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (6 bytes)
 02 00 8a 00 00 05
SDR record ID   : 0x008a
SDR record type : 0x01
SDR record next : 0x00b9
SDR record bytes: 51
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x23
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (6 bytes)
 02 00 b9 00 00 05
SDR record ID   : 0x00b9
SDR record type : 0x02
SDR record next : 0x00ba
SDR record bytes: 31
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x23
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (6 bytes)
 02 00 ba 00 00 05
SDR record ID   : 0x00ba
SDR record type : 0x02
SDR record next : 0x00bd
SDR record bytes: 31
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x23
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (6 bytes)
 02 00 bd 00 00 05
SDR record ID   : 0x00bd
SDR record type : 0x02
SDR record next : 0x00ca
SDR record bytes: 36
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x23
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (6 bytes)
 02 00 ca 00 00 05
SDR record ID   : 0x00ca
SDR record type : 0x01
SDR record next : 0x00cd
SDR record bytes: 51
OpenIPMI Request Message Header:
  netfn     = 0xa
  cmd       = 0x23
OpenIPMI Request Message Data (6 bytes)
 02 00 cd 00 00 05
SDR record ID   : 0x00cd
SDR record type : 0x02
SDR record next : 0xffff
SDR record bytes: 30
```

---

Follow the advice from @Lenniey, I issue following command:

```
$ sudo ipmitool -v raw 0xa 0x11
Running Get PICMG Properties my_addr 0x20, transit 0, target 0
Error response 0xc1 from Get PICMG Properities
Running Get VSO Capabilities my_addr 0x20, transit 0, target 0
Invalid completion code received: Invalid command
Discovered IPMB address 0x0
RAW REQ (channel=0x0 netfn=0xa lun=0x0 cmd=0x11 data_len=0)
Unable to send RAW command (channel=0x0 netfn=0xa lun=0x0 cmd=0x11 rsp=0xc7): 
Request data length invalid
```

Here raises another question: How to get raw command clues from the output of `sudo ipmitool fru -vvv` ?

Comment: I don't think you can use `raw` to extract this information. But anyway, could you edit the output of `sudo ipmitool fru -vvv`? Also: you can try your luck with this document: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/servers/ipmi/ipmi-second-gen-interface-spec-v2-rev1-1.html

Comment: @Lenniey, thanks for your quick response, I've added the output of `ipmitool fru -vvv` in my question.

Comment: try `sudo ipmitool -v raw 0xa 0x11` or something like that.

Comment: @Lenniey, I've added the result to the end of the context, but I have another question: How to get the raw command clues from the output of `sudo ipmitool fru -vvv` ? and are you familiar with using OpenIPMI API in C code, I just want to set some unique number as the product serial number. Not really need the Board Serial field. It can be the Product Serial as well.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't know more but I think with some tinkering you might be able to get what you need

Comment: @Lenniey, it's OK. I installed the `ipmitool` from the source, modified the C code in the `lib` folder, added some func to get the information from the func call by `ipmitool sensor`, `ipmitool mc info` ,plus, I parsed the file `/proc/cpuinfo` to get the CPU model type. It's good enough for me to continue my project. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: Woah, alright, sounds a bit extreme but whatever works :) You could add it as an answer, maybe.

Answer (score 1):

To read the FRU you need to use the following command:

```
ipmitool raw 0xa 0x11 <offset lsb> <offset msb> <count>
```

You will need to calculate the offset of the board serial but that you can do with some trial and error (or actually do the math).

The response will be

- First byte: number of bytes read.
- Second byte onwards: the raw data that was read.